# Get views of a Youtube video for specific location/country (API v3)

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to get the number of views of a Youtube video in a specific region/country. In that way, it should be possible to tell from which countries the views from a video came from.

I tried to use Youtube search list (API v3), where the parameters *location* and *locationradius* can be given. Using these parameters, you get a video that was posted in that region, but this video is often not relevant at all. The parameter *regioncode* contains data about whether a specific video is allowed in a certain country. So this is not the correct approach either.

Another thing I tried is to get information from channels, but I can not get insight data of channels that I have no authentication key to.

Can anyone help me in getting the number of views of a Youtube video in a specific region/country?

Comment: If the videos are on *your* channel, you may(?) find this info in the Analytics > Audience menu. I don't think this is available for videos outside of your own.